# Basic configuration required for hadoop installation

Tags: java, hadoop, hardware

What is the basic configuration required in a system to install hadoop in psuedo-distributed mode? 
Capacity of the following:
1.RAM
2.Processor
3.Hard disk etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Follow any tutorial to setup hadoop on your machine. Here is a good document by Micheal Noll.
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

You can even refer Apache website for detailed explaination of prerequisites and installation procedure to setup hadoop.
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Hadoop is designed to run on [commodity hardware](http://www.revelytix.com/?q=content/commodity-hardware) (affordable hardware). I think if your are using hadoop for learning or experimental purpose, then 2GB of RAM, 40 GB HDD and dual core processor will do your stuff. I would prefer to setup a linux environment rather than using VM on windows. 
To try out on windows using VM ware, you can download VM sandbox freely available from various vendors such as [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products.html?productID=F6mO278Rvo) or [Hortonworks](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/) etc.

Comment: Thank you Ankur for ur reply. Sorry i already have read all those stuffs u have mentioned here. But my real question is not how to install but the configuration required for the system. Question such as 1.Does 2 gb RAM capacity is enough 2.What kind of processor we need to support hadoop 3.It is better to install it in windows using VM ware or else we can try it out with Linux itself. My real question is (what is the best and basic configuration for installing and runnng hadoop in Psuedo-distributed mode)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has helped you. Read this to get an idea of how accepting the answer works. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work